# Из-за чего теряется качество?

Tags: php, изображения, php7

```
$this->image = imagecreatefromwebp($filename);
 
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, $transfX, $transfY, $w_new, $h_new, $this->width, $this->height);
 
imageWebp($this->image, $save, 100);
```

Не понимаю, изначальное изображение webp, открываю, затем меняю размеры, все в пропорции. Далее сохраняю с максимальным качеством и при этом качество теряется. В чем дело?

Выставлять вместо 100, 20, качество становится хуже, выставлять максималку, качество лучше но все равно не то что у изначального изображения...

Comment: а вы делаете бОльшее разрешение картинки или меньшее?

Comment: Из большего изображения, делаю меньшее. Под размеры 315x200, если что та не помещается, обрезаю лишнее. В основном привожу к высоте 200 в пропорции к ширине, в большинстве случаем обрезаю ширину, выравнивая по центру.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функции GD в алгоритмах, где важна скорость работы. Где нужно лучшее качество, лучше использовать ImageMagick. Правда, не каждый PHP собран с поддержкой модуля ImageMagick. Да и сам ImageMagick должен быть откомпилирован с ключем `--with-webp`. На худой конец можете сохранять картинку в JPG.

```
$thumb = new Imagick('myimage.webp');

/* Фильтр LANCZOS делает магию Photoshop-а, 
   но в сравнении с GD ооочень медленно. */
$thumb->resizeImage($w_new, $h_new,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.webp');

$thumb->destroy();
```

Подробнее про методы ресайза есть хорошая [статья на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/243285/).

**UPD** Для сжатия c обрезкой можно использовать такую функцию

```
function thumbnail($image, $new_w, $new_h, $focus = 'center')
{
    $w = $image->getImageWidth();
    $h = $image->getImageHeight();

    if ($w > $h) {
        $resize_w = $w * $new_h / $h;
        $resize_h = $new_h;
    }
    else {
        $resize_w = $new_w;
        $resize_h = $h * $new_w / $w;
    }
    $image->resizeImage($resize_w, $resize_h,
                        Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9);

    switch ($focus) {
        case 'northwest':
            $image->cropImage($new_w, $new_h, 0, 0);
            break;

        case 'center':
            $image->cropImage($new_w, $new_h, 
                               ($resize_w - $new_w) / 2, 
                               ($resize_h - $new_h) / 2);
            break;

        case 'northeast':
            $image->cropImage($new_w, $new_h, 
                               $resize_w - $new_w, 0);
            break;

        case 'southwest':
            $image->cropImage($new_w, $new_h, 0, 
                               $resize_h - $new_h);
            break;

        case 'southeast':
            $image->cropImage($new_w, $new_h, 
                               $resize_w - $new_w, 
                               $resize_h - $new_h);
            break;
    }
}
```